# How to handle an optional value returned by a query using the postgres crate?

Tags: postgresql, rust

I'm trying to get a value for a query, but this value can be NULL and I don't know how to handle it in Rust. Here is my code:

```
let stmt = conn.prepare("SELECT * FROM pictures").unwrap();

for row in stmt.query(&[]).unwrap() {
    let id: i32 = row.get("id");
    let author: String = row.get("author");
    let description: String = row.get("description");

    let rating: String = row.get("rating");

    let gps_lat: String = row.get("gps_lat");
    let gps_long: String = row.get("gps_long");
    let date_taken: chrono::NaiveDate = row.get("date_taken");

    println!("id        -> {}\n
           author      -> {}\n
           description -> {}\n
           rating      -> {}\n
           gps_lat     -> {}\n
           gps_long    -> {}\n
           date        -> {}\n
       ", id, author, description, rating, gps_lat, gps_long, date_taken);
}
```

When I execute the code, the first picture comes well because the rating column isn't NULL. But the second picture fails and gives me "Conversion(WasNull)", because there is not rating and I try to convert a NULL into a chrono::NaiveDate.

Comment: A wild guess: load fields which can be NULL as `Option`s. I don't understand from your wording whether it's `date` or `rating` can be NULL in your case, but if it's the latter, it would look like this: `let rating: Option<String> = row.get("rating");`.

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in [the documentation](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.15.2/postgres/types/trait.FromSql.html#nullability):

> #### Nullability
>
> In addition to the types listed above, `FromSql` is implemented for
>   `Option<T>` where `T` implements `FromSql`. An `Option<T>` represents a
>   nullable Postgres value.

Request an `Option<Type>` for the field that can be NULL; then the library will automatically convert NULL to `None`:

```
let rating: Option<String> = row.get("rating");
```

Comment: what about get_opt() ?

Comment: @Tom The [documentation for `get_opt`](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.15.2/postgres/rows/struct.Row.html#method.get_opt) states: *Returns `None` if the index does not reference a column*. If you have a nullable column that also might not be in the row, then you'd end up with an `Option<Option<T>>`.